# boto3 and AWS Athena permission

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to use `boto3`, v. 1.7.4, to interact with AWS Athena through the following script:

```
import boto3
import botocore

# Test access to the input bucket
bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('s3_input')
print(list(bucket.objects.all())

client = boto3.client('athena', region_name='us-east-1')

# Create a new database
db_query = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS france;'
response = client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString=db_query,
    ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': 's3_output'})

# Create a new table
table_query = '''
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS france.by_script (`content` string ) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('separatorChar' = ',')
LOCATION 's3_input';'''

response = client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString=table_query,
    ResultConfiguration={'s3_output'},
    QueryExecutionContext={'Database': 'france'})
```

With the current permissions of my account, the test to read the content of `s3_input` works well. I can also create the database through the `db_query` but the table creation fails with the following error message:

```
Your query has the following errors:FAILED: Execution Error, return
code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
MetaException(message:Got exception: java.io.IOException
com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS
Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code:
AccessDenied; Request ID: [...]), S3 Extended Request ID: [...])
```

If I run the `table_query` command from the console, [console.aws.amazon.com/athena/home](https://console.aws.amazon.com/athena/home), using the same account, there is no problem and the table is properly created.

The permissions are

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": "s3:GetObject",
           "Resource": "s3_input"
       },
       {
           "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": [
               "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
               "s3:HeadBucket"
           ],
           "Resource": "*"
       }
   ]
}
```

I would be happy to understand what I am missing here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which query in your code is causing the error? What permissions do you have attached to the role that your code is using? (Presumably, a role attached to an EC2 instance?)

Comment: The last query, creating the table, fails. The role has read/write access to s3_output and read access to s3_input.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the permissions? In fact, can you edit your question and show the policies? It's not clear which bucket is causing the error, but I would suspect the input bucket, which would need ListBucket and GetObject permissions, perhaps others.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to create policy for the user who needs to run athena query from Boto3.

```
-- S3 files bucket: sqladmin-cloudtrail
-- S3 output bucket: aws-athena-query-results-XXXXXXXXXX-us-east-1

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-athena-query-results-XXXXXXXXXX-us-east-1",
                "arn:aws:s3:::sqladmin-cloudtrail"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-athena-query-results-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-us-east-1/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sqladmin-cloudtrail",
                "arn:aws:s3:::sqladmin-cloudtrail/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "athena:StartQueryExecution",
                "athena:CreateNamedQuery",
                "athena:RunQuery"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my blog I did for an automation: https://www.sqlgossip.com/automate-aws-athena-create-partition-on-daily-basis/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem as above, but in addition to the permissions mentioned by Flavien in the answer above my process (a Lambda function) needed to add also **s3:PutObject** and **s3:AbortMultipartUpload**.

Athena apparently creates objects named like folderName_$Folder$ in the SOURCE data folders, so it needs to have PutObject permission to that (not just read-only). Don't ask me why the AbortMultipartUpload is needed... but it comes straight from Athena docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/access.html

The entire statement for your IAM policy looks like this:

```
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::your-source-data-bucket-name*"
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the following permissions make it work

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": [
               "s3:Get*",
               "s3:List*"
           ],
           "Resource": "*"
       }
   ]
}
```

Comment: i have problem with exactly same error message and i do have the above policy as a part of role for my lambda function, but it does not help. just like you, i have full read access to the data bucket and full s3 access to the result output bucket. any other ideas?